# is file creation atomic in windows xp?

Tags: c#, windows, file, windows-xp, atomic

HI,
I would like to use the file system as a lock between two processes, on windows xp.
i.e. given a file name "file_lock", a process acquires the lock by trying to create
the file "file_lock" if it doesn't already exist. If already exists, fails to get the lock.

i.e.

```
FileStream fs=new FileStream("c:\\file_lock, FileMode.CreateNew);
```

Will this work? Is file creation if file doesn't already exist atomic?

Thanks!

Comment: How could it not be atomic? Then two processes could create different files with the same name.

Comment: move is an alias of copy and delete, create is create.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it will work. But not as well as a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28VS.85%29.aspx) for many reasons including:

1. What if the user doesn't have access to create that file?
2. When your app crashes, the system cleans up Mutex locks. It won't delete your file for you.
3. Why introduce the overhead and risk of disk IO unnecessarily? (and I'm not sure if this is possible, but while the file is open, a user can rename or move it, right?)
4. It's more code.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I am managing a local cache on disk, to cache frames of video data. Each frame is put in its own folder. I want one lock per frame, so that's why I chose the file based approach. Also, I like the fact that the lock file is not cleaned up on crash; this gives me information on whether the folder was written correctly, or was only partially written before the crash.

Answer (score 0):

As the question has been tagged as C#, this answer no longer applies, but I would like to leave it in case it would be helpful for others in the future.

If you're using Java, you could use `java.nio.channels.FileLock`.

To use it, do something like this:

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.FileLock;
...
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
FileLock lock = raf.getChannel().tryLock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, false);
if (lock != null && lock.isValid()) {
    // You've acquired the lock!
else {
    // You did not acquire the lock
    raf.close();
}
```

Note: This protects against access from other processes, but not other threads. You'll need to use your own internal synchronization for that (locking on `raf` would probably work).

Comment: The style, specifically the name of the symbolic constant, looks more like C# than Java.

Comment: @Ben It does, but without a language tag, it could be assumed that any language that runs on XP is acceptable. The code snippet above just looks like pseudocode to me.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to use the file as a sync lock i suggest you the next procedure.

1. Check for the file lock/exists
2. If file is locked the other process is working
3. If file doesn't exists or have no lock you can adquire it
4. Open the file adquiring the lock

This code can help you checking for the lock.

```
public static bool isFileLocked(string filename)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename)) throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found!", filename);

    FileStream fs = null;
    try
    {
        fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        return false;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fs != null)
        {
            fs.Close();
            fs = null;
        }
    }
}
```

HTH!

Comment: Also, I need the method to create the file if it doesn't exist, otherwise, fail.  FileStream fs=new FileStream("c:\\file_lock, FileMode.CreateNew);

Comment: You sould do something like if (!File.Exists(filename)) and if the file doesn't exists create it or if you are using the function i gave to you you can catch the FileNotFoundException in your code and create it.

Comment: Hi SubniC: I think you got downvote because you didn't address the atomic issue, and your method didn't provide the create if not exists functionality. Nonetheless, your feedback is appreciated!

Comment: jeje, ok mate, i was not writting your code, i was giving you some insight in what to do, trying to match the way you say you want to do it... and as i told you i dont understand the context of the atomic thing... how can the file creation not be atomic? at least at your level of control in high level languages such c# or Java